# Browser back button with history API

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history

I want to use HTML5 history api and classical links with `<a>` tag.

I start from `/page1/` and load resource `/recource/` with ajax.

Then I push history state with `window.history.pushState(push_data, document.title, url)`. Then I go to another page by classic link `<a href = '/page2'>`  and click on the back button in the browser. But instead of showing the page `/page1/` modified or not it shows me the data from `/resource/` page - just plain-text data or json or whatelse you have in `/rescource/`.

How can I make the browser mix history api and classic links?

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly what you did.

You were on: `/page1` which is on the top of the stack, then pushed `/resource`, then pushed
`/page2`. So the stack looks like this.

```
/page2
/resource
/page1
```

The History API just allows developers to push the URLs (and objects with some data) and nothing more... For example: If you say that the web page of animals you just created should push the state of `google.com` then you will have on the stack google.com and when clicking the back button you will really go to google.com.

The most important thing on the web is that the URL represents some data. So you should not push the `/resource` URL in the history stack when the URL is not working or displaying something different - for now your example linked the `/resource` URL with two not identical things

1. The web page which shows the content of `/resource`
2. The `/resource` file itself

But they are not the same!
This is why you should push something like `/page1WithLoadedResource` or (I think the best) `/page1/resource` or `page1?loaded=resource` or anything which just work for you and make SURE that this URL does what you want when you just enter it in the browser and it does not matter whether you serve in on the server or on the client... On the client you could display just blank page template and then load the `/resource` by AJAX exactly as you did when starting on `/page1` and loading `/resource`.

You could do it much easier when using some of the Client MVC/MVVM framework but that goes much further from a scope of this question but you should always link the URLs with resources for bookmarking, processing, REST APIs and more and more...